# Get the first record of every 1000 items in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want get the first record of every 1000 items in laravel.

Also sorted by `updated_at` desc

**Example Data:**

(id: 1000 & updated_at: 2017)

(id: 1001 & updated_at: 2018)

(id: 1002 & updated_at: 2016)

... more records ...

(id: 2000 & updated_at: 2017)

(id: 2001 & updated_at: 2018)

(id: 2002 & updated_at: 2016)

... more records ...

(id: 3000 & updated_at: 2017)

(id: 3001 & updated_at: 2018)

(id: 3002 & updated_at: 2016)

**Result:**

(id: 1001 & updated_at: 2018)

(id: 2001 & updated_at: 2018)

(id: 3001 & updated_at: 2018)

---

update:

with this code i get first record but i want sorted it like above example.

```
$items = Item::chunk(1000, function ($items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo $item->title . "<br>";
        break;
    }
});
```

---

Update2:

thanks all ♥

I wirte this code with your help and this works fine.

Now this method is good way? do have good performance?

```
$output = collect([]);
$items = Item::chunk(1000, function (Collection $items) use ($output) {
    $output->push($items->sortByDesc('updated_at')->first());
});
dd($output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant answer perhaps something with the looks of laravel pagination would be better. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

```
$countItems = Item::count();
$output = collect([]);
$i = 0;
while($i<$countItems){
    $i+=1000;
    if($i>$countItems)
        break;
    $output->push(Item::orderBy('id','desc')->skip($i)->first());
}
dd($output->sortByDesc('updated_at'));
```

Comment: Thanks very much ♥ Your code is good. i with a few change resolve this problem. Please see my update2 in querstion. Do you think this is a good way? This does not use the server resources badly?
Thanks.

Comment: I belive the way you have it now is ideal, pretty sure you don't over query, if you want to make sure, look into this package, it allows you to see all the queries being made and much more https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Answer (score 0):

This is not as hard as it seems. Check out the nth() collection method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-nth

```
$data = Model::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get()
$newStuff = $data->nth(1000)
```

Edit:
There is also the slice() method. Which will return parts of the collection by index as the first parameter, then amount returned as the second.

```
Use Method of your choice for looping over the collection
$array[] = $data->slice(x, 1000)->sortByDesc('updated_at')->first();
```

Where x is the loop logic to set the first item (so it starts at 1, then goes to 1001, 2001, 3001, etc). This will give you an array of what you're looking for. May have to tinker with it a bit to get the exact index you need.

Comment: Thankful. But I do not want all the records to be sorted. Only 1000 to 1000 will be arranged and first taken. Please see my example.

Comment: See the edit. This will save you from having to do a lot of Database calls. If the original collection is massive then it may be faster to go the query builder route, since SQL is faster than PHP at huge datasets.

Comment: this code work well for me:          $output = collect([]);
        $items = Item::chunk(1000, function (Collection $items) use ($output) {
            $output->push($items->sortByDesc('updated_at')->first());
        });
       dd($output);
it have good performance?  thanks

Comment: Yes, that seems like it would be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
$items = Item::orderBy('updated_at','desc')->get()->chunk(1000);

foreach ($items as $item) {

        echo $oneitem->title . "<br>";
        break;

    }
```

Comment: every 1000 record

Comment: thanks. but i want sort by each 1000 record. similar to my example. your code sort all records in table.